# Geocoding and reverse geocoding using search bar based on IPhone GPS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm making an iPhone location based app and I'm having trouble with one of its aspects. I was wondering if anyone knows how to integrate a search bar that correlates with iPhone GPS coordinates without using mapkit view

It's literally a search bar in the storyboard wherein on search button being clicked the user gets the address of the location based on iPhone GPS location.

Is this possible?

I've looked around for tutorials and implemented it using a LABEL and BUTTON but i would like to implement it using a search bar if its possible.... by the way I am a newbie ..

Any help will be much appreciated... here is how i implemented it...

```
- (IBAction)userlocation:(id)sender 
{

    LocManager.delegate=self;
    LocManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [LocManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [LocManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [LocManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    CLLocation *currentlocation= [locations lastObject];

    if(currentlocation!=nil){

       self.Latitude.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentlocation.coordinate.latitude];
       self.Longitude.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentlocation.coordinate.longitude];

    }

    [LocManager stopUpdatingLocation];


[Geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentlocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error==nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {

            Placemark= [placemarks lastObject];

            self.address.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n",           
                        Placemark.postalCode,
                        Placemark.locality,
                        Placemark.administrativeArea,
                        Placemark.country];
        }else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    }];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"Failed to get location! ");

}
```

Comment: if you got the address the simply set to your search bar (like: searchBar.text = @"Your address"). what the issue here ?

Comment: could you please be bit more specific with your solution...